# Indicator function, a sequence of integrals: find the parameter $a$ such as the limit is finite

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

This is an example of the problem for which I would really appreciate a detailed explanation.

We have $\alpha >0$ and $\chi_A$ as the indicator function of the set A. For $n\in N$ we have:

$$f_n(x)= \chi_{[\frac{1}{n}, 1]}(x)\cdot n\cdot\ln(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha})~~~~\text{for}~~x>0$$

I have to determine, **for which values of $\alpha>0$** the sequence of integrals:
$$\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx$$
has a **finite limit**. Furthermore, the value of the limit is expected to be **calculated**.

I would love to show my own attemps - however, in this case, I would ask you for a step-by-step solution or a good explanation. Additionally, how to interpret $\chi_{[\frac{1}{n}, 1]}$? That $\{\frac{1}{n},1\}$ is the subset of A?

Comment: The function  $\chi_{\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right] }$ should be interpreted as the indicator function of the interval $\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right] $, and, since it is multiplying the other terms, that
$$
f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right), & \mbox{if } x\in\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right] \\ 0, & \mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right..
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts, we get
$$
\int_{1/n}^1n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)dx = \left[nx\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)\right]_{1/n}^1 - \int_{1/n}^1 nx\cdot\left(\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)\right)'dx,
$$
where
$$
nx\cdot\left(\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)\right)'= nx\frac{nx^\alpha}{1+nx^\alpha}\left(1+\frac{1}{nx^\alpha}\right)'=nx\frac{nx^\alpha}{1+nx^\alpha}\frac{-\alpha}{n}x^{-\alpha-1} = -\alpha \frac{1}{x^\alpha+\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
So
$$
\int_{1/n}^1n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)dx = \left[nx\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)\right]_{1/n}^1 +\alpha \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{x^\alpha+\frac{1}{n}}dx
$$
Now, let us evaluate the limit for each case below:

1. For $\alpha<1$. Observing that $\frac{1}{x^\alpha+\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\chi_{\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]}\nearrow \frac{1}{x^\alpha}\cdot\chi_{[0,1]}$ and using the Monotone Convergence Theorem we get
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{x^\alpha+\frac{1}{n}}dx = \alpha\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^\alpha}dx = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}.
   $$
   On the other hand, we have
   $$
   \left[nx\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)\right]_{1/n}^1 = \ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) - \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\right).
   $$
   Since $(1+1/n)^n \to e$, we get that $\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)\to \ln(e) = 1$ and since $1-\alpha>0$, we have $n^{1-\alpha} \to \infty$, and consequently, $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}}\right) \to 0$.

Putting it all together, we derive that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^1n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)dx = 1-0 + \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha},
$$
whenever $0<\alpha<1$.

2. For $\alpha=1$, we follow the same path as before, but with a different result. Using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, we get that
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^1 \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{n}}dx = \alpha\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx = +\infty,
   $$
   and
   $$
   \left[nx\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)\right]_{1/n}^1 = \ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) - \ln(2) \to 1- \ln(2).
   $$
   Therefore,
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^1n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx}{nx}\right)dx = +\infty.
   $$
3. For $\alpha>1$, we prove that the limit also goes to infinity by following another path. First of all, observe that for each $x\in\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]$,
   $$f_n(x) = n\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{nx^\alpha}\right),$$
   and since $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is increasing, $x\mapsto \frac{1}{nx^\alpha}$ is decreasing, and, using thata $\ln$ is increasing, we get that
   $$
   f_n\ \mbox{is decreasing in $[1/n,1]$}.
   $$
   This implies that for any $x\in \left[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}\right]$ we must have
   $$
    f_n(x) \geq f_n(2/n) = n\cdot \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}}\right).
   $$
   Since this happens for any point in the interval $\left[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}\right]$, we have
   $$
   \int_{1/n}^1 f_n(x)dx \geq \left(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)f_n(2/n) = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}}\right).
   $$
   Now, notice that, since $\alpha>1$, $n^{1-\alpha}\to 0$, so $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}}\right) \to +\infty$ and consequently
   $$
   \int_{1/n}^1 f_n(x)dx \to +\infty,
   $$
   and we are finally done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I will analyze it and ask some questions if needed.

Comment: I hope it isn't too late, but could you explain, why in 3. case $f_n$ is decreasing since $\ln$ is increasing?

Comment: It follows from the fact: If $f$ is increasing and $g$ is decreasing, then $f\circ g$ is decreasing. To verify this fact, consider $x<y$. Since $g$ is decreasing, $g(y)<g(x)$. Then, since $f$ is increasing $f(g(y))<f(g(x))$. So $x<y$ implies that $f\circ g(y)< f\circ g(x)$, that is, $f\circ g$ is decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of we intergate over the interval $[\frac{1}{n}, 1]$, shouldn't we use Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Additionally, why do you integrate over $[\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ instead of $[0,\infty]$?

Comment: @Funny, when $f$ is continuous, the Lebesgue and the Riemann integrals of $f$ coincide, so it makes no difference. To answer your second question, note that $f_n$ vanishes outside $\left[\frac{1}{n}, 1\right]$ and coincides with $n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)$ inside $\left[\frac{1}{n}, 1\right]$, so $\int_0^{+\infty} f_n = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}f_n = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1}n\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1+nx^\alpha}{nx^\alpha}\right)$.